# If I were to place Dine-in, Takeaway, and Delivery into a category, what would be an appropriate title for the category?

Tags: food, category

So I have an application which displays a list of restaurants to a user. This list of restaurants can be filtered by cuisine, features etc. I want this list to be able to filtered by dine-in, takeaway, delivery. What would be an appropriate name for this category?

A user of the application should be able to read this name and be able to instantly realise the options that will be available to them upon selecting it. For example, the title of the cuisines category is simply "Cuisines". Anyone who reads this will know immediately know that if they select this category they will be presented with a list of cuisines.

I am finding it hard to come up with ideas, at the moment I have the title DTD, but I don't feel that this is descriptive enough. Others that I have considered but decided against are:

- Dine Options
- Eating Options
- Availability

Again, I don't feel like they are descriptive enough. When a user reads this title they should immediately know that if they select it, it will present them with the dine-in, takeaway, and delivery options. I think that if a user were to read any of these titles, they will not immediately understand what the title relates to without clicking it.

Comment: And you don't like them because...?

Answer (score 2):

"Service Mode: Dine-in/ Takeaway /Delivery/ Catering"
"Order Type: Dine-in/ Takeaway /Delivery/ Catering"
Just my 2c.

Comment: I like "service mode" because it seems to include both distribution method and location of the transfer of possession.